# XSL-FO: Format <fo:page-number/> as Roman Numerals

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I want to convert the value of `<fo:page-number/>` into roman numerals such as convert 1 to i, 2 to ii, 3 to iii, and so on. I don't find there is any attribute in `<fo:page-number/>` that can achieve this. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [@format attribute](https://www-data2type-de.translate.goog/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/format?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=nl&_x_tr_pto=wapp) of the `fo:page-sequence` element.

You will need

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="your-reference" format="i">
```

Comment: In case you don't speak german: The "format" attribute `i` represents small roman numerals and `I` represents capital roman numerals.

Comment: The various "format tokens" are defined in XSLT: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#convert ("A format token `i` generates the sequence `i ii iii iv v vi vii viii ix x ....`").

Comment: Since this is an [English-content](https://stackoverflow.com/help/non-english-questions) site, it would be better with a reference to documentation written in English.

Comment: @mzjn : I agree but I could not find a better explanation than this one. But with from google i changed my answer